# HTTP to HTTPS redirect for a specific domain through web.config

Tags: redirects, https, godaddy, configuration, web.config

I'm trying to do a HTTP to HTTPS redirect on a GoDaddy web hosting platform. I have the Windows hosting platform and I'm editing the web.config file. There are multiple domains under this hosting account, and **I'm trying to do the redirect for only ONE domain and its subdomains**.

Example:

- 5 domains: `domain1.example` , `domain2.example`, etc... and each domain may have subdomains

Desired behaviour:

- `*.domain1.example` redireced to `https://*.domain1.example` (with or without www)
- include a wildcard in front of the domain, to handle any sub-domains

This is what I started with, which will redirect every domain from HTTP to HTTPS, **and it works properly:**

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions> 
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now I tried to make it for a specific domain only, but I really have no idea how to write this myself. Instead I have put together some stuff I found online. I find all the `+?\` and `A-Za` quite confusing.

```
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?domain1\.example(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;\=]*)?)" /> 
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions> 
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

But this results in a 500 (internal server) error.

Comment: I removed the [Tag:htaccess] tag because it looks like you can't use an Apache based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <match url="(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?domain1\.example
> ```

I believe the `url` attribute matches URL-paths only, not the absolute URL, so this will never match. But if it did match, it's also matching `https`, which is not what you require.

Try just adding another *condition* to your original *rule* that checks the `HTTP_HOST` for the specific domain. For example:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+\.)?domain1\.example$" />
```